# gdb detaching after fork from child process - disable?

Tags: gdb, fork

Getting this message inside gdb. I know its not an error or anything. I also did pagination so thats not an issue.

Is there any way to suppress this message?

Comment: Since I did not get answers, it seems that my question is wrongly put. Let me rephrase it..

Q: gdb has pagination off option by which you can keep scrolling with whatever warnings you have. This works most of the time. I was able to suppress some interrupts and signals. 

BUT

When you are working with big binaries with multiple threads, fork, exec etc, it keeps on giving you various information/warnings.  Thats very irritating sometime.

Is there any way to suppress this warnings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was curious to see that this question was unanswered...

I obtained the [GDB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/), and it says (in part - p33 of the PDF 'Ninth Edition, for gdb version 7.0.50.20091228'):

> To be notified when inferiors are started or exit under gdb’s control use
>   `set print inferior-events`:
>
> ```
> set print inferior-events
> set print inferior-events on
> set print inferior-events off
> ```
>
> The `set print inferior-events` command allows you to enable or disable
>   printing of messages when gdb notices that new inferiors have started or that
>   inferiors have exited or have been detached. By default, these messages will
>   not be printed.
>
> ```
> show print inferior-events
> ```
>
> Show whether messages will be printed when gdb detects that inferiors have
>   started, exited or have been detached.

The only concern I have about this is that it implies that you should not be seeing the messages by default.  Just make sure that your settings match the default and do not override them.

Section 4.11 'Debugging Forks' (pp38-40) looks relevant to you, too.

Comment: This answer is true but irrelevant. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

I tried `set print inferior-events off`, but it didn't disable the message. Actually, `print inferior-events` was already off even before I tried to turn it off.

I looked through the `gdb` source code, and found that `print inferior-events` controls printing of the messages `"[New inferior %d]"`, `"[Inferior %d exited]"`, and `"[Inferior %d detached]"` only.

The message `Detaching after fork from child process` is controlled by the `verbose` and `debug lin-lwp` options, instead. However, **on Fedora systems the message is always printed** because they have a patch (namely `gdb-6.6-bz235197-fork-detach-info.patch`) that turns

> `if (info_verbose || debug_linux_nat)`

into

> `if (1 /* Fedora Bug 235197 */ || info_verbose || debug_linux_nat)`

. So you can never turn it off, unless you remove the patch from the source and compile it again.

Comment: When was that patch applied to Fedora?  And, all the world is not running Fedora - and the original question did not specify Linux, let alone Fedora.  You've done some interesting research, but a Fedora-specific patch does not affect the generality of GDB users.  Your answer may be relevant to some people; but your blanket assertion that the original answer, which was useful for a couple of years, is irrelevant seems a little OTT.

Comment: Jonathan, please note that I was just adding information for Fedora users at the end (because I happened to have the same problem on Fedora), and everything I mentioned before "However" is applicable to all systems, because it's directly from the original source of `gdb-7.3`. In particular, on any system, **`set print inferior-events off` does not turn off the message `Detaching after fork from child process`.**

I cannot say for sure when the patch was applied, but the file `gdb-6.6-bz235197-fork-detach-info.patch` was in `gdb-7.2-52.fc14.src.rpm`, and the patch file was dated 2011-11-09.