# Ignor detaching log in GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

When I debug process with GDB I saw logs like:

`[Detaching after fork from child process XXXX]`

How can I stop print those log in gdb script?

Comment: Does [`set print inferior-events off`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html#index-set-print-inferior_002devents-182) work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gdb detaching after fork from child process - disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637389/gdb-detaching-after-fork-from-child-process-disable)